# Launch AHK vs sitting idle in sys tray

Tags: autohotkey

This may seem like an obvious answer, but I have a AHK script that works when I press the assigned key, but I am wondering is there a way to fire off the script when I double click on the script icon?

Currently when I double click on the .ahk file it just opens in my sys tray and sits idle until I hit the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default**, MenuItemName: Changes the menu's default item to be MenuItemName and makes that item's font bold. When the user double-clicks the tray icon, its default menu item is launched.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm#Add_or_Change_Items_in_a_Menu

```
; auto-execute section
Menu, TRAY, Add
Menu, Tray, Add, run Notepad (Double Click), run_Notepad 
; Menu, Tray, Icon, run Notepad (Double Click), %A_WinDir%\Notepad.exe
Menu, TRAY, Default, run notepad (Double Click)
   return  ; end auto-execute section


run_Notepad:
F1::
Run notepad
return
```

EDIT: Sorry, I missunderstood your question.
Double click on the script icon or press F1 to run the editor:

```
; auto-execute section:
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force   
GoSub, run_Notepad
      return  ; end auto-execute section


run_Notepad:
F1::
Run notepad
return
```

Comment: Thanks that works,  but I am still required to double click the icon in the system tray (to launch the script) of course.   I guess,  I am trying to find out if there is a way to launch the script say without a key stroke.   So that I could auto launch it as a scheduled task / Cron ?